# Export RDLC to only one sheet instead of many sheets

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have applied **Page break** and display **page size** of 10 records, then while exporting to **excel** 10 sheets are created. I want all pages in one sheet only instead of 10 different sheets. Can anybody help to come out of this.

Comment: Are all your records within the confines of 8.5 X 11 inches (at least, this is the standard paper size in the USA)?

Comment: yes it is confines in 8.5 X 11 inches only.But suppose I have 9 pages , each of 10 records then 9 sheets in workbook is created.I want all in one sheet.

Comment: To me this isn't a technical question yet; but a logical one.  How can you start with 9 sheets and end with 1 sheet?  You must change the program to generate only a single sheet instead of multiple.  You have to shrink your records down so that they will fit on a single page.  But, if there are dozens of records, there's isn't much you can do to keep them all on one page. Maybe you can post process your PDF to put all pages on one page by shrinking them down?

Comment: Thanks all this problem is resolved.